# How I can add the perimeter method in my code?

Tags: c#, methods

```cs
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int s = 2;
            int area = s * s;
            int perimeter = s * 4;
            Console.WriteLine("Area is " + area);
            Console.WriteLine("Perimeter is " + perimeter);

            s = 6;

            int areaValue = areaFunction(s);
            Console.WriteLine("The area is " + areaValue);

            int areaFunction(int side)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The passed parameter has value" + side);
                int areaV;
                areaV = side * side;
                return areaV;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do it with the area and worked but with perimeter no. Someone can show me how I should add the perimeter method in my code( Methods and c# in general are new subjects for me).Thanks.( and sorry for grammatical mistakes. English isn't my first language).

Answer (score -1):

You're currently defining your `areaFunction` inside another method (the `Main`), try placing it ouside of that. And start the `areaFunction` method with `public static int`.

If you want to make a method for a static method, then both methods needs to be static.
And the public part defines it's accessability to other classes.

So far I see you're using parameters well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to stick to this structure as a start:

What you have done is defining an inner function in a method.

Probably also good to read about the [static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FunctionA(5);
        }
        
        public static int FunctionA(int side)
        {            
            return areaV;
        }
    }
}
```